# How to get entire dataset from dataloader in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, dataloader

How to load entire dataset from the DataLoader? I am getting only one batch of dataset.

This is my code

```
dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=dataset, batch_size=64)
images, labels = next(iter(dataloader))
```

Comment: Does `image_batches, label_batches = zip(*[batch for batch in dataloader])` give you what you want? This may take a lot of memory and time depending on the size of your dataset.

Answer (score 14):

You can set `batch_size = len(dataset)`. Beware, this might require a lot of memory depending upon your dataset.

Comment: You can also do `len(dataset)` for torch datasets. To be able to do so is the sole purpose of implementing the `-_len__()` method.

Answer (score 12):

Another option would be to get the entire dataset directly, without using the dataloader, like so :

```
images, labels = dataset[:]
```

Comment: Note that this is a great one-liner, but only if you don't have any transformation in your dataloader (like collate_fn or something else)

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure if you want to use the dataset somewhere else than network training (like inspecting the images for example) or want to iterate over the batches during training.

**Iterating through the dataset**

Either follow Usman Ali's answer (which might overflow) your memory or you could do

```
for i in range(len(dataset)): # or i, image in enumerate(dataset)
    images, labels = dataset[i] # or whatever your dataset returns
```

You are able to write `dataset[i]` because you implemented `__len__` and `__getitem__` in your `Dataset` class (as long as it's a subclass of the Pytorch `Dataset` class).

**Getting all batches from the dataloader**

The way I understand your question is that you want to retrieve all batches to train the network with. You should understand that `iter` gives you an iterator of the dataloader (if you're not familiar with the concept of iterators see the [wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator)). `next` tells the iterator to give you the next item.

So, in contrast to an iterator traversing a list the dataloader always returns a next item. List iterators stop at some point. I assume that you have something like a number of epochs and a number of steps per epoch. Then your code would look like this

```
for i in range(epochs):
    # some code
    for j in range(steps_per_epoch):
        images, labels = next(iter(dataloader))
        prediction = net(images)
        loss = net.loss(prediction, labels)
        ...
```

Be careful with `next(iter(dataloader))`. If you wanted to iterate through a list this might also work because Python caches objects but you could end up with a new iterator every time that starts at index 0 again. To avoid this take out the iterator to the top, like so:

```
iterator = iter(dataloader)
for i in range(epochs):
    for j in range(steps_per_epoch):
        images, labels = next(iterator)
```